# ctx.canvas.toBlob((blob) => { run inside for loop

Tags: javascript

How to run ctx.canvas.toBlob one by one inside loop with clear memory?
show "SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED" error in browser while run in loop.

```
for(quality= 1; quality >= 0.10;quality=parseFloat(quality-0.02).toFixed(2)){

ctx.canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
if(blob.size < XX) {
Bloburl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}
}, 'image/jpeg', quality);

}
```

Example:

Loop 1:  Run ctx.canvas.toBlob Qulity: 1 => size: 100KB

Loop 2:  Run ctx.canvas.toBlob Qulity: 0.98 => size: 94KB

Loop 3:  Run ctx.canvas.toBlob Qulity: 0.96 => size: 91KB

Loop 4:  Run ctx.canvas.toBlob Qulity: 0.94 => size: 85KB

While size goes to less than X than stop loop and stop ctx.canvas.toBlob

Comment: Why are you doing `parseFloat` around `quality-0.02`? That expression is already a float. If anything, use `(parseFloat(quality) - 0.02)` or `(Number(quality) - 0.02)`. What do you mean by “clear memory”? Why exactly does the code you currently have not work?

Comment: Where are those 45 blobs going to be stored?

Comment: show "SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED" error in browser while run in loop

Comment: Also, instead of attempting a linear search for the optimal quality parameter, try a bisection approach.

Comment: ctx.canvas.toBlob when blob size bellow to specific size then break loop and stop ruining ctx.canvas.toBlob

Comment: @MitGuru does this mean there is a missing break in your for loop as shown in your question? Also, can you show how the canvas is created and do you get the error whatever size/complexity?

Comment: @MitGuru, you are creating a large number of blobs, all with quality 0.08. This is because one blob creation doesn't finish before another one begins. You need to get them sequential and let the next one overwrite its predecessor otherwise you will rack up space usage - even though the blobs are at the smaller quality. I will put some code in an answer.

Comment: i want to calculate blob size in loop with reduce quality until less than X size. when size less than X. then create blob url and stop ctx.canvas.toBlob function to run further.
Example:

Loop 1:  Run ctx.canvas.toBlob Qulity: 1 => size: 100KB
Loop 2:  Run ctx.canvas.toBlob Qulity: 0.98 => size: 94KB
Loop 3:  Run ctx.canvas.toBlob Qulity: 0.96 => size: 91KB
Loop 4:  Run ctx.canvas.toBlob Qulity: 0.94 => size: 85KB

While size goes to less than X than stop loop and stop ctx.canvas.toBlob

Comment: @user4642212 it is essential to pass a floating point number to toBlob - I found it necessary to invoke parseFloat on the quality value being passed (otherwise I think it gets passed as a string to a function). See comment in the code on my answer.

Comment: @AHaworth That’s even worse, then, because OP’s code _always_ passes a string due to the (unnecessary) `.toFixed(2)` call. This fact still doesn’t change the validity of my comment that `parseFloat(quality - 0.02)` is an unnecessary use of `parseFloat`.

Comment: @user4642212 yes it is unnecessary in the for I think  (I could have taken it out) but it is necessary in the actual call to .toBlob because it's been passed to a function (trying it without gives a weird - and consistently weird - quality value passed to .toBlob)

Comment: @AHaworth Or just skip the `toFixed` call and set `quality -= 0.02`. Then it’s always a number. How “weird” can a [default value of `0.92` for `image/jpeg` and `0.8` for `image/webp` for non-number arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob#Parameters) be?

Comment: @user4642212 I think the questioner wanted a number with only 2 decimal figures after the decimal point. If you keep subtracting 0.02 from quality you end up with rounding errors. Also if  you pass quality which has been passed to a function as is to .toBlob it does not get picked up by .toBlob as a floating point number - try an experiment. It took me ages to track this down! Sometimes I wish JS had proper data-typing - including actual integers.

Comment: @AHaworth JavaScript already has integers. _“if you pass quality which has been passed to a function as is to .toBlob it does not get picked up by .toBlob as a floating point number”_ — `toBlob` ignores anything that isn’t a number within the range `0` to `1`. What is “a function”? If you pass a string, e.g. the return value of `toFixed`, then, _of course_, that would not meet the expected argument of `toBlob`. _“a number with only 2 decimal figures after the decimal point”_ — IEEE-754 floating point numbers have no concept of decimals after the point. `0.02` is always going to be imprecise.

Comment: @user4642212 agreed that JS deals with integers to a certain extent, but  limited compared to some other languages However, that's me drifting off topic somewhat. On topic: agreed that the standard's FP numbers have no concept of a decimal after the point - but human's do and it seemed important to the questioner so I kept it in. Yes, the problem that took me time was realising that I was passing quality to a function as a string  and it needed to be a number for .toBlob. That was me being slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code given in the question sort of assumes that things are happening synchronously.

The problem is that the call canvas.toBlob does not instantaneously create a blob, it uses a callback function when it has done so.

If you put console.log statements in the code, one just after the for and one in the callback function, you will see that the for loop finishes before any of the callback functions are executed.

What we need to do is get the first blob, check it, then if it's not suitable get the next one and so on

You can see an example at https://rgspaces.org.uk/blobtest.html -
look at the Console log in dev tools.

Here's the code:

```
 <img id="img" src="https://rgspaces.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/Readingrep.jpg" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300 style="visibility:hidden;"></canvas>
    <script>
    window.onload=init;
    
    function init() {
      var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
      var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
      var Bloburl="";
   
      ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById("img"), 0, 0, 300, 300);
     
      findSuitableBlob();
    
      async function findSuitableBlob() {
        var suitableQuality=false;
        var blob;
          for(var quality= 1; quality >= 0.10;quality=parseFloat(quality-0.02).toFixed(2))
          {
            blob = await getCanvasBlob(canvas,quality);
            console.log("With quality="+quality+" blob.size="+blob.size);
            if (blob.size<10000) {//this is XX - set it to whatever you require
              suitableQuality=quality;
              Bloburl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
              break;
            }
          }
          if (suitableQuality) { 
            console.log("I found a blob of suitable size. Its quality="+suitableQuality+" What shall I do now?");
          }
          else { 
            console.log("I can't find a blob which is small enough.");
          }
        
        function getCanvasBlob(canvas,quality) {
          return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
              resolve(blob);
            },'image/jpeg',parseFloat(quality))// Note - quality must be passed as a number to toBlob 
          });
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```